# Rational root theorem: $w^k x^n+... +w^h =0$

Tags: polynomials

I need validation on my understanding here.

Assume a polynomial with integer coefficients $w^k x^n+... +w^h =0$ where $k<h$ are integers too. We know this polynomial has either integer roots or complex roots. So no rational but not integer roots.

We know that *if* it has rational roots in the form $p/q$ then $p$ divides $w^h$ and $q$ divides $w^k$.

But can we say *if* it has an integer root, that root certainly divides $w^{h-k} $?

**Edit**
It's important to know if there is any integer $u$ that the root can be written as $w^{h-k} u$. The sign of $u$ doesn't matter.

Comment: are all intermediate coefficients multiples of $w^k$?

Comment: No unfortunately. If they were then I could factor out $w^k$ and use integral root theorem

Answer (score 1):

No. For example, $$(4x^2+1)(x-8)=4x^3-32x^2+x-8=0$$ has an integer root $x=8$ which does not divide $2=2^{3-2}.$

Comment: $1/4$ is another root. But we know the polynomial has either integer or complex roots.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If you do not allow rational roots that are not integers, the answer is still No.